# Resolving "WebSphere application server v7 is currently running" message in IBM Installation Manager on Windows 7

Tags: updates, websphere-7, ibm-installation-manager

I received the message "WebSphere application server v7 is currently running. Please shut it down to continue." while attempting to upgrade my local version of WebSphere Application Server 7 using IBM Installation Manager on Windows 7. The server was not running at the time. The message also persisted after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199141), any running Java process can cause this issue. I found a running instance of javaw.exe using Process Manager, closed it, and the installation was able to proceed from there.